# Stuck at tty 23.10 can't able to apt update

Tags: apt, updates, internet, tty

Can't able to apt update. And can't able to leave tty.

Can't even able to ping google.com
When I try aprm update:
Ign:1
And I have a doubt on my source list too.
I think I have issue with internet connectivity but I don't know how to check weather I connect to internet or not so I tried to ping google.com it showes (temporary failure in name resolution).
I don't know to solve it

Help me

Comment: It does not help If you are posted your question twice.